# Django runserver not working; error: Python was not found. Did I miss something?

Tags: python, django, windows

It's been a while since I posted anything here, and now my problems have become more advanced. For reference, I'm running on Win10.

I'm trying to use the Django framework. Python's been installed on my computer forever; it's the latest version, and it's installed on environment variables/added to system paths. I *think* those are enabled by default, but I did make sure that they were checked when I reinstalled it.

pip's been updated too. Django installed successfully. I managed to get all the way to installing my new project with `django-admin startproject PROJECTNAME`, but when I try to run `python3 manage.py runserver`, I'm getting this error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

This "Python was not found" error is the main problem that I'm trying to figure out. Nothing I do as a fix seems to get rid of it.

...Interesting. If I type in `python --version`, I get a response (Python 3.11.0). Here's what I get if I do **pip freeze**:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.1.6
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.7
```

Python IDLE runs fine; all .py files run fine. Alright. So, with that in mind and in accordance to a lot of popular advice I've seen floating around, I added the Path to my Environment Variables. For space-saving reasons, my Python is installed on my D drive rather than C. I've made sure that there weren't any leftover Python files that conflicted.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled, double checked my installations, and Django is in `D:\ProgramData\Python311\Scripts` with pip and everything else I need. I did also disable the shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases, but when I did that, I got this error:

```
python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Based on some other things I've seen, I've also tried:

```
python manage.py runserver
python3 ./manage.py runserver
```

I ended up having to enable the options again just to use Python correctly. And I have been closing and reopening the command line whenever I make changes. Though it updates automatically to fit what I've been doing, I wanted to make sure I didn't overlook any possibility.

I even uninstalled Django for a third time, installed the virtual environment (which I realised I skipped), and did it all again. And then, after a *long* series of figuring out how to activate the virtual environment and enabling scripts to run, I'm finally in `(venv) D:\PROJECTNAME`, and I tried... to run it again.

I'm still getting the Python not found error. orz

I've been at it for two hours or so, and I feel like I'm running into a dead end. I think I've finally met my match here.

This is my first time using frameworks like this, and it's been a *while* since I've installed anything through command line on Windows. I'm not very great at this, so I know that I'm making some amateurish mistakes somewhere. Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or missed something obvious.

Please.... I just want to use Django....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably didn't install for all users.  I would press the start button and type Edit Environmental Variable for both user and admin.

Comment: @jdweng I did install for all users, and I made sure that I was running as administrator to make sure everything went through.

Comment: Check the environmental variables.  Both Admin and User should have the path and/or PSModulePath.  The installer could be bad.

Comment: @jdweng I went ahead and double checked my environmental variables before editing the post, and everything seems to be in order Admin and User.

Comment: Then is has to be a privilege issue.  That the path (and or PSModulePath) is correct but the executable is not found.  Do you need subprocess? https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/

Comment: Read through, copy and pasted the file details into mine, and I'm getting an error: `TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd'`; when I put the cmd as an argument just in case, I get `NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined`.

Comment: Why is this tagged Powershell? This is not PowerShell/PowerShell code issue.  You are running python.exe directly. One can run ```*.exe``` from a PowerShell console; ***see this:***  [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) ; but you must pass it all it requires, and all your ```Environment``` and ```PowerShell``` ***paths***, must be correct. Otherwise, you must specify the FQDN to the ```*.exe```.  ```$env:PSModulePath``` &````cmd /c path``

Comment: @postanote Sorry, I ended up tagging it with PowerShell because that was what I was working in to get all of this running. The only times I used Python.exe directly was to make sure that everything was running. (I was following a step-by-step tutorial that was working in PS before I ran into this issue.)

Comment: If the command `python3` does not work, but the command `python` does, then ... just use `python`.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon I did think of that in the in-between, but still no luck. I had to run Python again to get the exact error I saw:  `Python WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` and I've done nothing different between PS and Python.

Answer (score 0):

This question really is not proper for a PowerShell Q&A, but let see if the below helps.

If you are trying to run django from PS, then:

```
pip install django
django-admin startproject YourProjectNamehere
```

lastly, hit your dev server

```
HTTP://YourDevServerName:YourDevServerPortNumber
```

Also, be sure that you've activated your virtual environment, never assume it is until you test it. Of course, be sure to change directly to the root of your project.

Again, if you are using python, directly, then, it's more prudent to stay in your pristine python shell vs executing from a PowerShell consoler/terminal, thus eliminating any PowerShell particulars.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I really appreciate it. I was running this in PS, which is why it was tagged with it. I was trying to cover my bases. So, I think the only thing from this I'll have to try is hitting my dev server like you suggested. I assumed that my virtual environment was active because my PS changed my directory to (venv) D:\, but this is all new territory for me. 

I'll give this a shot.

Comment: No worries. When I am working with customers and students I deliver classes to, I have to regularly remind them that if X or Y thingy does not work in the pristine X or Y thingy native environments, then any attempt to run elsewhere is really a wasted effort. Specifically due to additional steps that may be required in the non-native thingy.

Answer (score 0):

first download manually python on your computer from official website "https://www.python.org/" , therefore install django from official website "https://www.djangoproject.com/download/",
and install python and django on your computer ...

if you're on linux,on your terminal type "sudo pip install Django==4.1.6"

after installing that  type , django-admin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).